# Tradeoffs of disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection) in order to install Sierra on Mac Pro (Early 2009)

Tags: macos, security, upgrade, sip

Lets say someone wants to upgrade a Mac Pro (Early 2009) to macOS Sierra in order to get core security updates and newer versions of modern software.

Unfortunately this Mac Pro model is not officially supported for macOS Sierra. However, there is a patch tool in existence which will update the firmware on the machine that would allow the installation of Sierra.

**The problem is that it requires SIP to be permanently disabled.**

Setting aside all the [multitudes of] *other related* security concerns (i.e. *"uh, patch tool?"*)...

**Would the security threat of disabling SIP outweigh the added security benefit of OS patches from Apple and new software from 3rd party vendors?**

Comment: 4.1 Mac Pro doesn't need SIP disabled if the firmware update is applied... I'm typing this on a 4,1 running Mojave... with SIP enabled.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's so awesome to hear. At any point did you disable SIP?

Comment: I honestly can't remember. I periodically disable to fiddle with things, but not specifically for updates etc. I've marched this one onwards & upwards since El Capitan without issue. [It has a proper Mac-flashed Metal-capable GPU so I don't have to worry about the blank screen at boot]

Comment: Tetsujin... just a thought, you ought to make that an answer...

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok, noted. Good point on the metal cards also, I'll need to look into that.

Comment: I can't really add an answer that says nothing more than "It worked for me". I bought this machine with the 5.1 firmware already installed, so other than googling the process itself, I don't really know.

Comment: @Steve_Chambers Well, the question is more about SIP security vs Apple core updates. Tetsujin didn't answer the question with his comment; essentially he indicated that it _wasn't_ a question since SIP didn't need disabling in the first place.